# Primefaces datatable lazyloading pagination number of rows are wrongly displayed

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces, pagination

I am trying to implement lazyloading for Primefaces datatable. I have a filter condition which I have implemented as

```
public List<Request> getRequest(int startingAt, int maxPerPage,
            String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, 
String> filters) {
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
            createCriteria(Request.class);          
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : filters.entrySet()) {            
            if(entry.getValue()!=null){             
                criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("prNo",
                "%"+entry.getValue()+"%"));             
            }
        }
        criteria.setMaxResults(maxPerPage);
        criteria.setFirstResult(startingAt);
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

and in jsf page

```
<p:column id="prNo" filterBy="#{req.prNo}"   
                headerText="PR No">                 
                <h:outputText value="#{req.prNo}" />
            </p:column>
```

The issue I am facing is when filtered rows displays n datatable pagination numbers doesn't change at all, it shows as of the actual number of records.
E.g. If filter matches a condition and number of rows for filter condition is 12, then pagination should display as **1 of 3** and pages should be like **1 2 3**. See the attached screen shot.[image]

Lazymodel rowCount is set as

```
lazyModel.setRowCount(getRequestService().getRequestCount());
```

it's implementation

```
int count = ((Long) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("select count(*) from Request").uniqueResult())
                .intValue();
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: When you filtering your data , make sure that `setRowCount` will be set with a size of the filtered data something like `lazyModel.setRowCount(criteria.list().size());`

Comment: @Daniel If I am not using DataModel for LazyLoading what is the best approach to get `criteria.list().size()` in managedbean? And is it a good idea of not using DataModel for LazyLoading and overide load method directly in managedbean?

Comment: INMO , you better use `LazyDataModel` (extend it just like in the showcase) , inside your overridden `load` method you should do the filter logic and have the result , than get its size and use it...

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to implement LazyDataModel and for some reason I am getting nullpointer exception. I have created a new post for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967915/getting-nullpointer-exception-in-datamodel-class-when-dao-method-is-being-called

Comment: @Daniel If you post an answer I will be very glad to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INMO , you better use `LazyDataModel` ([extend it just like in the showcase - DataTable - Lazy Loading](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf))

Inside your overridden load method you should do the filter logic and have the result , than get its size and use it...